# Not able to convert JSON to Java class (call WebApi from Android app)

Tags: java, c#, android, json

im working on my school project and im new in android programming but i have some programming experiance in c# and .net.

This is my code:

```
    public class ProizvodiAPI {

    public class ProizvodiVM implements Serializable
    {
        public Integer proizvodID;
        public String naziv;
        public String sifra;
        public BigDecimal cijena;
        public Byte[] slikaThumb;
        public String jedinicaMjere;
        public String vrstaProizvoda;
    }
        public class ProizvodiLista implements Serializable
        {
            public  List<ProizvodiVM> proizvodi;
        }
public static void GetAllProizvode(final MyRunnable<ProizvodiLista> onSuccess)
    {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApp.getContext());
        String url = "Proizvodi/GetProizvodiVM";

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Config.urlApi + url,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                        final Gson gson = MyGson.build();
                        final ProizvodiLista model = gson.fromJson(response, ProizvodiLista.class);
                        onSuccess.run(model);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {

                Toast.makeText(MyApp.getContext() , "That didn't work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Program crashes here:

```
final ProizvodiLista model = gson.fromJson(response, ProizvodiLista.class);
```

Is the problem with deserializing json, if it is, shoud i change the Java class and what to change ?

Here is my C# class in Web Api:

```
 public class Proizvodi
    {
        public int ProizvodID { get; set; }
        public string Naziv { get; set; }
        public string Sifra { get; set; }
        public decimal Cijena { get; set; }
        public byte[] SlikaThumb { get; set; }

        public string JedinicaMjere { get; set; }
        public string VrstaProizvoda { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: And what is the value of the response you are trying to convert into ProizvodiLista.class?

Comment: This is my response from fidler (result is same in "response" variable in android)

http://vpaste.net/VIuVC

PS: I exclude public byte[] SlikaThumb from both, C# and Jaca class but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response you are receiving, it is a JSONArray and not a simple JSONObject. Deserialize it properly.